# Cannot Find Symbol Error, No Typos and Arguments are correct

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm getting a cannot find symbol error on a method I implemented, but the spelling and arguments are exactly what they're supposed to be.  What's going on?

Method I'm trying to implement:

```
    public static Comparable[] heapify(Comparable[] array){
    int index = array.length - 1;
    Comparable temp;

    if (index == 1){
        return array;
    }

    else{
        for (int i = index; i >= 0; i++){
            while(array[i/2] != null && array[i/2].compareTo(array[i]) > 0){
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i/2];
                array[i/2] = temp;
                index = index/2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test program that is implementing the method:

```
Comparable[] array = {2,5,8,12,10,6,4};
Heap heapified = heapify(array);
heapified.printHeap();
```

EDIT: Added Compiler error

```
G:\Labs\Lab_10>javac Test.java
Test.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            Heap heapified = heapify(array);
                             ^
  symbol:   method heapify(Comparable[])
  location: class Test
Note: .\Heap.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Comment: Please provide the **exact** compilation error + relevant row directed by the compiler

Comment: Did you *import* the class implementing `heapify()`? Also, note that the method returns a `Comparable[]` and not a `Heap`.

Comment: The main method is where I'm calling it.  And the two classes are in the same folder.  The test program is calling other methods from the same class as heapify with no issue.  And thanks for pointing that heap thing out.

Comment: you said two classes? then probably you should access it as `ClassName.heapify()` not just `heapify()`.

Comment: Ack, I knew it was going to be something stupid like that.  It's been a while since I've been coding and I keep forgetting little things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide some more information. Right now it's too little to help.

But, my guesses are :

1. Method "heapify(Comparable[])" is in diffrent class so you musr write :

   > Heap heapified = CLASS_WITH_HEAPIFY.heapify(array);
2. Check your imports in main class. Maybe your not importing the right package with Class containing 'heapify'